# Magento 2 : How do I hide a Customized Checkout Step

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, shipping-methods

I have added a **custom step** in **checkout**. I would like to use some JS to hide or disable the step based on if the associated shipping option is selected or not. 
I tried to wrap it in if statement but failed, so I might just be placing the if statement incorrectly. 
The error returned in console was `"document.getElementById(...) is null"`.

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template, 
    * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of the your module directory.
    * 
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'ICA_Customshipping/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(true),


        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
    //My attempt to wrap it in an if statement has failed           
    if(document.getElementById('s_method_icacustomshipping_icacustomshipping').checked) {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'step_code',
                //step alias
                null,
                //step title value
                'Step Title',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                * sort order value
                * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                15
            );

            return this;

            }
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step 
        */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

Comment: did you get some solution for this